# Why does my minecraft username not change?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I went to the Minecraft website, and my username DID change, but it isn't changing in the launcher. It also won't let me join multiplayer servers because my account is "not authenticated with Minecraft.net." :/

Comment: No, I haven't, but I found the answer. I figured it was just a small glitch, nothing to really make a fuss about :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured it out :D
What I needed to do was log out of the launcher, and then back in!
Hope that makes sense to anyone who encounters the same issue :3